# How to align text in center in android ? Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout in that linear layout I have put one text view. its only showing text in the center when RTL support is on. I want the text to be aligned in the center. because now I am false the RTL support.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="sdfhhsdfsbn fdsbdfsj  uufudbdsjk jfdsufjdbfsd jfdsud dfsodlkbdljodfsugfsd oidfshoudslds fdsohds"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:textColor="#666666" />
```

Comment: Try setting `layout_width` to `match_parent`. And read about `android:gravity` property for text views.

Answer (score 0):

Update your TextView as follows

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text="sdfhhsdfsbn fdsbdfsj  uufudbdsjk jfdsufjdbfsd jfdsud dfsodlkbdljodfsugfsd oidfshoudslds fdsohds"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:textColor="#666666" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change textview width

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add   `android:gravity="center"` in your text view to align the text in center.

`gravity` sets the gravity of the contents of the View.

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="sdfhhsdfsbn fdsbdfsj  uufudbdsjk jfdsufjdbfsd jfdsud dfsodlkbdljodfsugfsd oidfshoudslds fdsohds"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:textColor="#666666" 
            android:gravity="center"/>
```

I hope its work for you.